# Python: How to loop next parameter pages

Tags: python, python-requests, python-responses

- How to loop next parameter pages
- How to bring this value to the next loop parameter? =>> "next": "/api/v2/intelligence/?q=%28%28status%3D%27active%27%29+and+%28confidence+%3E%3D+100%29+and+%28country+%3D+TH%29+or+%28country+%3D+AD%29%29&search_after=1466972229598%2C288044306&limit=1000"

  ```
  import requests
  import json

  host='https://api.threatstream.com'
  api_key ="apikey"
  user = "user@user.co.th"

  def get_data(url):
  headers = {
   "Content-Type": "application/json",
   "Authorization": "apikey " + user + ":" + api_key
  }

  final_url= host + url
  response = requests.get(final_url, verify=False, headers=headers)

  data = response.json()
  print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

  if (response.status_code == 200):
     print("status_code = " + str(response.status_code) + " The request was a success!")
     if data.get('meta',{}).get(next) :
       get_data(data.meta.next)

  elif (response.status_code == 404):
       print("status_code = " + str(response.status_code) + " Result not found!")

  url = "/api/v2/intelligence/?&q=((status='active') and (confidence >= 100) and (country = TH) or (country = AD))"

  get_data(url)
  ```
- Response data

  ```
  "meta": {
   "total_count": 1154,
   "offset": 0,
   "limit": 1000,
   "took": 185,
   # How to bring this value to the next loop parameter?   
   "next": "/api/v2/intelligence/?q=%28%28status%3D%27active%27%29+and+%28confidence+%3E%3D+100%29+and+%28country+%3D+TH%29+or+%28country+%3D+AD%29%29&search_after=1466972229598%2C288044306&limit=1000" 

   }
   status_code = 200 The request was a success!
  ```

Comment: I would just update `url` with the next one.

Comment: What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You can recursively call the function to fetch data, if the response code is 200 and response json has next url .

```
import requests
import json

host='https://api.api.com'
api_key ="apikey"
user = "user@user.co.th"

def get_data(url):
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "apikey " + user + ":" + api_key
    }
    
    final_url= host + url
    response = requests.get(final_url, verify=False, headers=headers)

    data = response.json()
    print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

    if (response.status_code == 200):
        print("status_code = " + str(response.status_code) + " The request was a success!")
        if data.meta.next:
            get_data(data.meta.next)

    elif (response.status_code == 404):
        print("status_code = " + str(response.status_code) + " Result not found!")
        
url = "/api/v2/intelligence/?&q=((status='status') and (confidence >= 'confidence') and (country = 'country'))"

get_data(url)
```

Comment: Thanks you. Please: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\xampp\htdocs\API\api-next\apinextpage\nextpage1.py", line 27, in <module>    
    get_data(url)
  File "c:\xampp\htdocs\API\api-next\apinextpage\nextpage1.py", line 21, in get_data    
    if response.meta.next:
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'meta'
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\API>

Comment: Thanks, I've done what you suggested. Still no results. Please: Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\xampp\htdocs\API\api-next\apinextpage\nextpage1.py", line 27, in <module> get_data(url) File "c:\xampp\htdocs\API\api-next\apinextpage\nextpage1.py", line 21, in get_data if response.meta.next: AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'meta' PS C:\xampp\htdocs\API>

Comment: i cant help further, since this url seems to be incorrect https://api.api.com

Comment: The url is the api that I took the example from. So if to open the correct url i am afraid of corrupt company data please how would you advise me to share it with you?

Comment: can you copy the code and try now, I have made some corrections @T.o1

Comment: Thanks, I did as you suggested, response data but not loop next "meta": {
        "total_count": 1154,
        "offset": 0,
        "limit": 1000,
        "took": 217,
        "next": "/api/v2/intelligence/?q=%28%28status%3D%27active%27%29+and+%28confidence+%3E%3D+100%29+and+%28country+%3D+TH%29+ or+%28country+%3D+AD%29%29&search_after=1466972229598%2C288044306&limit=1000"
    }
}
status_code = 200 The request was a success!

Comment: Please: Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\xampp\htdocs\API\api-next\apinextpage\nextpage1.py", line 32, in <module> get_data(url) File "c:\xampp\ htdocs\API\api-next\apinextpage\nextpage1.py", line 24, in get_data if data.meta.next: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'meta' PS C:\xampp\htdocs\API>

Comment: you can simply update the api host as host (which will be your company's host )and try copy the code, i have updated again, notice how final_url is being constructed

Comment: Thanks, I followed the instructions and updated the code, ran the code, it says line 30 and line 22 are not recognized.
Please: Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\xampp\htdocs\API\api-next\apinextpage\nextpage3.py", line 30, in <module> get_data(url) File "c:\xampp\ htdocs\API\api-next\apinextpage\nextpage3.py", line 22, in get_data if data.meta.next: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'meta' PS C:\xampp\htdocs\API>

Comment: basically your api is not sending the response, you can put a check like this if if data.get('meta',{}).get(next) instead of if data.meta.next: in the code

Comment: Thanks, I put a check like this if data.get('meta',{}).get(next) : instead of if data.meta.next: in the code. but line 34 and line 27 are still not recognized.
Please: Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\xampp\htdocs\API\api-next\apinextpage\nextpage3.py", line 34, in <module> get_data(url) File "c:\xampp\ htdocs\API\api-next\apinextpage\nextpage3.py", line 27, in get_data if data.meta.next: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'meta' PS C:\xampp\htdocs\API>

Comment: I updated the latest code above.

Comment: Thanks, Please, I did as you suggested, but it doesn't loop parameter page and what can I do next?

Comment: Please Please Please